# How to avoid running initial observeEvent of dynamically added input

Tags: r, shiny

When a dynamic input element is added to the UI it will trigger its already existing observeEvent. In particular, see the example below where the textInput is added dynamically at the first load of the server side function. Then when it renders the observeEvent will be triggered.

Is there a way in which we can generically avoid this triggering on addition of the input element, in particular, I would like testing input 1 and testing input 2 two fire in a similar fashion, that is, not at initiation.

The UI.R file

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

 fluidRow(
   uiOutput("my_output"),
   textInput(inputId = "test2", label = "test2", value = "start value"))

))
```

The server.R file

```
library(shiny)

first.load <- TRUE
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  if(first.load){
    output$my_output <- renderUI({
      textInput(inputId = "test", label = "test", value = NULL)
    })
  }

  observeEvent(input$test2,{
    browser()
  }, ignoreInit = T)

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    browser()
  }, ignoreInit = T)
})
```

Comment: Had the same problem once, with some javascript that created the input.

Answer (score 1):

The `obServeEvent` is reacting to the presence of `input$test`. So when it is initialized with a `value = ""` the `observeEvent` will fire since `""` is still a non-null value. As a quick fix you can wrap the `observeEvent` in a logic to only run if `input$test` is not equal to `""`:

```
observeEvent(input$test, {
    if (!input$test == ""){
       browser()
    }
  }, ignoreInit = T)
})
```

Comment: Even if I do not provide it a value, or provide it NULL, it will fire. But that would actually be beside the point of my question. I want the dynamic adding of such element to function as it would when it would be predetermined.