# ignoreInit not working with dynamic content

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

This is a cross post from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2292) to get more traction.

I recognized that `observeEvent` is triggered upon start when the UI is created dynamically, even with `ignoreInit=TRUE`. I found this thread on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865465/how-to-avoid-running-initial-observeevent-of-dynamically-added-input), but the presented solution does not work for `checkboxInput` because the value of the `eventExpr` is either `T/F`, so it's not possible to decide if it's the first call during initialization or a regular call.

In the minimal working example below I found a workaround by using `shinyjs::delay`, but I am not sure if this would always work and what minimum delay time is required.

To me, `ignoreInit` should also work for dynamic UIs, i.e. the observer for `dynamicBox` should not be triggered upon initialization as is the case for `staticBox`. Is there any chance to fix that issue or is this expected behavior?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "observeEvent ignoreInit"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("staticBox", "static"),
    uiOutput("body"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$body <- renderUI( tagList(
    checkboxInput("dynamicBox", "dynamic"),
    checkboxInput("dynamicBoxDelayed", "dynamic delayed")
  ))

  # observe static checkBox
  observeEvent(input$staticBox, {
    cat("observeEvent of static checkBox is executed\n")
  }, ignoreInit=TRUE)

  # observe dynamic checkBox
  observeEvent(input$dynamicBox, {
    # this is executed upon start, although ignoreInit is set to TRUE
    cat("observeEvent of dynamic checkBox is executed\n")
    cat( paste0("dynamicBox value = '", input$dynamicBox, "'\n") )
  }, ignoreInit=TRUE)

  # observe dynamicDelayed checkBox
  shinyjs::delay(100, {
    observeEvent(input$dynamicBoxDelayed, {
      cat("observeEvent of dynamic checkBoxDelayed is executed\n")
    }, ignoreInit=TRUE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I had the same problem with checkboxes and change from NULL before render to boolean after render, so the fix is just a flag that is check inside observer that is modified after first call.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't comment due to missing reputation, but here are my thoughts:

I guess the observeEvent does get blocked while initializing. But after that you render the UI Element. The input$dynamicBox changes from NULL to FALSE which triggers the observeEvent function.

You could fake the behavior by introducing a unique global variable within the session, say unique_init_variable <<- FALSE and then change it to true once you've used the checkbox. Here's an example code

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "observeEvent ignoreInit"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("staticBox", "static"),
    uiOutput("body"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # unique init variable
  unique_init_variable <<- FALSE

  output$body <- renderUI( tagList(
    checkboxInput("dynamicBox", "dynamic"),
    checkboxInput("dynamicBoxDelayed", "dynamic delayed")
  ))

  # observe static checkBox
  observeEvent(input$staticBox, {
    cat("observeEvent of static checkBox is executed\n")
  }, ignoreInit=TRUE)

  # observe dynamic checkBox
  observeEvent(input$dynamicBox, {
    if (input$dynamicBox == TRUE) {
      unique_init_variable <<- TRUE
    }
    if (unique_init_variable) {
      # this is executed upon start, although ignoreInit is set to TRUE
      cat("observeEvent of dynamic checkBox is executed\n")
      cat( paste0("dynamicBox value = '", input$dynamicBox, "'\n") )
    }
  }, ignoreInit=TRUE)

  # observe dynamicDelayed checkBox
  shinyjs::delay(100, {
    observeEvent(input$dynamicBoxDelayed, {
      cat("observeEvent of dynamic checkBoxDelayed is executed\n")
    }, ignoreInit=TRUE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Using a variable to ignore the first call is a similar work around than using `shinyjs::delay` in the original post. Since I do not understand why `ignoreInit` is not working, I cannot be sure that the workarounds always work. Interestingly, if `checkboxInput("dynamicBox", "dynamic")` is replaced with `actionButton("dynamicBox", "button")`, the program works as expected.
From my real program I have reason to believe that the GUI elements are not created when the server code is executed, as if there were two threads, but I did not yet come up with a minimal example demonstrating that.